# Discord message collector repeats collected message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make my Discord bot to detect when two or more similar messages are sent in a short time, and then send one message.

I'm having trouble understanding collectors so it just repeats the message over and over. Should I switch to await messages?

```js
const filter = m => m.content.toLowerCase() == message.content.toLowerCase();
const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, {max: 2, time: 6000});
collector.on('collect', m => {
    message.channel.send(message.content);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `max` value to `1` in the `createMessageCollector` options if you want to send a message as soon as there are two messages with the same content in that six seconds.

Also, you don't want to send a message every time a message is collected. If you set the `max` to `1`, you can subscribe to the `collector`'s `end` event and send the message from there once there are two identical messages. As the `end` event also fires when there are no identical messages within that timeframe, you will also need to check the `collected.size` and only send a message if it's greater than zero.

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  const filter = (m) => m.content.toLowerCase() === message.content.toLowerCase();
  const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, {
    max: 1,
    time: 6000,
  });

  collector.on('collect', (m) => {
    console.log(`Collected ${m.content}`);
  });

  collector.on('end', (collected) => {
    console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`);

    if (collected.size > 0) {
      message.channel.send(
        `Naughty, naughty! You sent _"${message.content}"_ more than once in a short time...`,
      );
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error too when I was first using collectors. The trick is that you have to stop the collector. Even if someone does answer.

So, the code would be:

```
collector.on("collect", m => {
    message.channel.send(message.content)l
    collector.stop()
});
```

I'm sure there is probably a logical explanation and an alternative approach, but this worked for me and it's pretty easy.

Comment: thankssssss it kinda worked, tho it stills sends 2 messages :/ idk why